# What makes "debuild -S" fail with "command not found" when "dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S" succeeds?

Tags: package-management

Consider the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ex

wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz
wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source -x ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
cd ocaml-re-1.7.3
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S || exit $?
debuild -S || exit $?
```

When I run it, I see

```
+ wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
--2018-10-28 20:29:03--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.162, 91.189.88.149, 91.189.91.23, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

+ wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz
--2018-10-28 20:29:03--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.162, 91.189.88.149, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

+ wget -N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz
--2018-10-28 20:29:03--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocaml-re/ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.162, 91.189.88.149, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

+ dpkg-source -x ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
dpkg-source: warning: extracting unsigned source package (ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc)
dpkg-source: info: extracting ocaml-re in ocaml-re-1.7.3
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz
+ cd ocaml-re-1.7.3
+ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S
dpkg-buildpackage: source package ocaml-re
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.7.3-2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Mehdi Dogguy <mehdi@debian.org>
 dpkg-source --before-build ocaml-re-1.7.3
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with ocaml
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
        make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jgross/Documents/repos/coq-debian-build-scripts/ocaml-stuff/debian-sources/foo/ocaml-re-1.7.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jgross/Documents/repos/coq-debian-build-scripts/ocaml-stuff/debian-sources/foo/ocaml-re-1.7.3'
   dh_ocamlclean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b ocaml-re-1.7.3
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building ocaml-re using existing ./ocaml-re_1.7.3.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building ocaml-re in ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building ocaml-re in ocaml-re_1.7.3-2.dsc
 dpkg-genchanges -S >../ocaml-re_1.7.3-2_source.changes
dpkg-genchanges: not including original source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build ocaml-re-1.7.3
dpkg-buildpackage: binary and diff upload (original source NOT included)
+ debuild -S
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S
dpkg-buildpackage: source package ocaml-re
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.7.3-2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Mehdi Dogguy <mehdi@debian.org>
 dpkg-source --before-build ocaml-re-1.7.3
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with ocaml
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
        make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jgross/Documents/repos/coq-debian-build-scripts/ocaml-stuff/debian-sources/foo/ocaml-re-1.7.3'
make[1]: jbuilder: Command not found
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jgross/Documents/repos/coq-debian-build-scripts/ocaml-stuff/debian-sources/foo/ocaml-re-1.7.3'
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 clean returned exit code 2
debian/rules:13: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I am baffled by the fact that, although I have jbuilder installed (via opam), `debuild -S` cannot find it, even though it seems to just be running `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S` which succeeds just fine.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the manpage, I discovered the [section on environment variables](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/debuild.1.html#environment%20variables), which says:

> As environment variables can affect the building  of  a  package,  often  unintentionally,
>          debuild  sanitises  the environment by removing all environment variables except for `TERM`,
>          `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `GNUPGHOME`, `PGPPATH`, `GPG_AGENT_INFO`, `FAKEROOTKEY`, `DEB_*`, the (`C`,  `CPP`,  `CXX`,
>          `LD`  and `F`)`FLAGS` variables and their `_APPEND` counterparts and the locale variables `LANG` and
>          `LC_*`.   `TERM`   is   set   to   `dumb`   if   it   is   unset,   and   `PATH`   is   set   to
>          `"/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11"`.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that one may add directories to the  beginning  of  the  sanitised  PATH,  using  the
>          `--prepend-path`  option.  This  is  useful  when  one wishes to use tools such as `ccache` or
>          `distcc` for building.

So the issue is that opam binaries are in `PATH` and thus not found here.